# Ubuntu 18.04, PyQt5, (not PySide2) conda, python: How to import QWebEngineWidgets?

Tags: python, ubuntu, import, pyqt5, conda

**Problem**:
The following line:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets
```

Gives me an error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2: symbol krb5_ser_context_init `version krb5_3_MIT not defined in file libkrb5.so.3 with link time reference`
```

It is strange because I installed `PyQt5` and `pyqtwebengine` in conda environment using pip and everthing should work fine.

**What I tried:**

1. I tried reinstalling libraries it did not resolve the problem [Python 3.7.0 No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51154871/python-3-7-0-no-module-named-pyqt5-qtwebenginewidgets)
2. I have no `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` set globally, so that cannot be a problem: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-843
3. [pyside2 installation problem on ubuntu18.04, python 3.8.3 on anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63186438/pyside2-installation-problem-on-ubuntu18-04-python-3-8-3-on-anaconda) The following solution is for `pyside2`, I tried to do analogously `conda install -c conda-forge PyQt5` however that did not solve my problem.
4. I tried to install `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5` but it did not help, so I removed it

I think that this problem is only for linux or conda, bacause my friend used Windows and pip and had no similar problems. Unfortunatly I have to use PyQt5 and conda, beacuse all rest of my code is based on it.

**Specifications**

I am using conda environment: i used both conda install and pip install in it: Below results of `(environment) user@user:~$ pip list` and `(environment) user@user:~$ conda list`

```
(environment) user@user:~$ pip list
Package            Version
------------------ -------------------
-yQt5              5.10
attrs              20.3.0
bgen-reader        3.0.2
biopython          1.78
bokeh              2.1.1
brotlipy           0.7.0
cachetools         4.1.1
certifi            2020.11.8
cffi               1.14.3
chardet            3.0.4
click              7.1.2
cloudpickle        1.6.0
coloredlogs        14.0
configparser       5.0.1
cryptography       3.2.1
cytoolz            0.11.0
cyvcf2             0.20.0
dask               2.30.0
dfply              0.3.3
dill               0.3.2
distributed        2.30.1
Flask              1.1.2
Flask-Cors         3.0.8
fsspec             0.8.3
glmnet             2.2.1
gtfparse           1.2.1
h5py               2.10.0
HeapDict           1.0.1
humanfriendly      8.2
idna               2.10
importlib-metadata 2.0.0
inflection         0.5.1
iniconfig          1.1.1
install            1.3.4
itsdangerous       1.1.0
Jinja2             2.11.2
joblib             0.16.0
locket             0.2.0
MarkupSafe         1.1.1
mkl-fft            1.2.0
mkl-random         1.1.1
mkl-service        2.3.0
more-itertools     8.6.0
mplcursors         0.3
mpld3              0.5.1
msgpack            1.0.0
multiprocess       0.70.10
numpy              1.18.1
olefile            0.46
packaging          20.4
pandas             1.1.0
partd              1.1.0
patsy              0.5.1
Pillow             5.4.1
pip                20.2.4
plotly             4.11.0
pluggy             0.13.1
psutil             5.7.2
py                 1.9.0
pyarrow            0.11.1
pycparser          2.20
pyliftover         0.4
pyOpenSSL          19.1.0
pyparsing          2.4.7
PyQt5              5.15.2
PyQt5-sip          12.8.1
PyQtWebEngine      5.15.2
pysam              0.16.0.1
PySocks            1.7.1
pytest             0.0.0
pytest-runner      5.2
python-dateutil    2.8.1
python-dotenv      0.15.0
pytz               2020.1
PyYAML             5.3.1
Quandl             3.5.2
requests           2.24.0
retrying           1.3.3
scikit-learn       0.23.2
scipy              1.5.0
setuptools         50.3.1.post20201107
sip                4.19.8
six                1.15.0
sklearn            0.0
sortedcontainers   2.2.2
statsmodels        0.11.1
tblib              1.7.0
texttable          1.6.2
threadpoolctl      2.1.0
toml               0.10.1
toolz              0.11.1
tornado            6.0.4
tqdm               4.51.0
typing-extensions  3.7.4.3
urllib3            1.25.11
vcfpy              0.13.3
Werkzeug           1.0.1
wheel              0.35.1
xarray             0.16.1
zict               2.0.0
zipp               3.4.0


(environment) user@user:~$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/user/anaconda3/envs/environment:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main  
almosthere                1.0.15               h46ee950_0    conda-forge
arrow-cpp                 0.11.1           py37h5c3f529_0  
attrs                     20.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
bgen                      3.0.2                h9db9d1d_0    conda-forge
bgen_reader               3.0.2            py37h14c3975_0    conda-forge
biopython                 1.78                     pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bokeh                     2.1.1                    py37_0  
boost-cpp                 1.68.0            h11c811c_1000    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py37h27cfd23_1003  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0  
ca-certificates           2020.10.14                    0  
cachetools                4.1.1                      py_0  
certifi                   2020.11.8        py37h06a4308_0  
cffi                      1.14.3           py37h261ae71_2  
chardet                   3.0.4           py37h06a4308_1003  
click                     7.1.2                      py_0  
cloudpickle               1.6.0                      py_0  
coloredlogs               14.0                     py37_0  
configparser              5.0.1                      py_0  
cryptography              3.2.1            py37h3c74f83_1  
cytoolz                   0.11.0           py37h7b6447c_0  
cyvcf2                    0.20.0           py37hcb143b1_1    bioconda
dask                      2.30.0                     py_0  
dask-core                 2.30.0                     py_0  
dfply                     0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
dill                      0.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
distributed               2.30.1           py37h06a4308_0  
flask                     1.1.2                      py_0  
flask-cors                3.0.8                      py_0    anaconda
freetype                  2.10.4               h5ab3b9f_0  
fsspec                    0.8.3                      py_0  
gflags                    2.2.2                he6710b0_0  
glmnet                    2.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
glog                      0.3.5                hf484d3e_1  
gtfparse                  1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0           py37hd6299e0_1  
hdf5                      1.10.6               hb1b8bf9_0  
heapdict                  1.0.1                      py_0  
htslib                    1.10.2               hd3b49d5_1    bioconda
humanfriendly             8.2                      py37_0  
icu                       58.2                 he6710b0_3  
idna                      2.10                       py_0  
importlib-metadata        2.0.0                      py_1  
importlib_metadata        2.0.0                         1  
inflection                0.5.1                    py37_0  
iniconfig                 1.1.1                      py_0  
install                   1.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2020.2                      254  
itsdangerous              1.1.0                    py37_0  
jinja2                    2.11.2                     py_0  
joblib                    0.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9b                   h024ee3a_2  
krb5                      1.18.2               h173b8e3_0  
ld_impl_linux-64          2.33.1               h53a641e_7  
libboost                  1.67.0               h46d08c1_4  
libcurl                   7.71.1               h20c2e04_1  
libdeflate                1.6                  h516909a_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         h14c3975_1  
libevent                  2.1.8                h1ba5d50_1  
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2  
libgcc-ng                 9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0  
libssh2                   1.9.0                h1ba5d50_1  
libstdcxx-ng              9.1.0                hdf63c60_0  
libtiff                   4.0.9                he85c1e1_2  
locket                    0.2.0                    py37_1  
lz4-c                     1.8.1.2              h14c3975_0  
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h14c3975_1  
mkl                       2020.2                      256  
mkl-service               2.3.0            py37he904b0f_0  
mkl_fft                   1.2.0            py37h23d657b_0  
mkl_random                1.1.1            py37h0573a6f_0  
more-itertools            8.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
mplcursors                0.3                      pypi_0    pypi
mpld3                     0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
msgpack-python            1.0.0            py37hfd86e86_1  
multiprocess              0.70.10                  pypi_0    pypi
ncurses                   6.2                  he6710b0_1  
numpy                     1.18.1           py37h4f9e942_0  
numpy-base                1.18.1           py37hde5b4d6_1  
olefile                   0.46                     py37_0  
openssl                   1.1.1h               h7b6447c_0  
packaging                 20.4                       py_0  
pandas                    1.1.0            py37he6710b0_0  
parquet-cpp               1.5.1                         3    conda-forge
partd                     1.1.0                      py_0  
patsy                     0.5.1                    py37_0  
pillow                    5.4.1            py37h34e0f95_0  
pip                       20.2.4                   pypi_0    pypi
plotly                    4.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pluggy                    0.13.1                   py37_0  
psutil                    5.7.2            py37h7b6447c_0  
py                        1.9.0                      py_0  
pyarrow                   0.11.1          py37hbbcf98d_1002    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2  
pyliftover                0.4                        py_0    bioconda
pyopenssl                 19.1.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0  
pyqt5                     5.10                     pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-sip                 12.8.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqtwebengine             5.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pysam                     0.16.0.1                 pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1                    py37_1  
pytest                    6.1.1                    py37_0  
pytest-runner             5.2                        py_0  
python                    3.7.7                hcff3b4d_5  
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0  
python-dotenv             0.15.0                   pypi_0    pypi
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
pytz                      2020.1                     py_0  
pyyaml                    5.3.1            py37h7b6447c_1  
quandl                    3.5.2                    py37_0  
readline                  8.0                  h7b6447c_0  
requests                  2.24.0                     py_0  
retrying                  1.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              0.23.2                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.5.0            py37h0b6359f_0  
setuptools                50.3.1           py37h06a4308_1  
sip                       4.19.8                   pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.15.0           py37h06a4308_0  
sklearn                   0.0                      pypi_0    pypi
snappy                    1.1.8                he6710b0_0  
sortedcontainers          2.2.2                      py_0  
sqlite                    3.33.0               h62c20be_0  
statsmodels               0.11.1           py37h7b6447c_0  
tblib                     1.7.0                      py_0  
texttable                 1.6.2                      py_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
thrift-cpp                0.11.0               h02b749d_3  
tk                        8.6.10               hbc83047_0  
toml                      0.10.1                     py_0  
toolz                     0.11.1                     py_0  
tornado                   6.0.4            py37h7b6447c_1  
tqdm                      4.51.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
typing_extensions         3.7.4.3                    py_0  
urllib3                   1.25.11                    py_0  
vcfpy                     0.13.3                   pypi_0    pypi
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0  
wheel                     0.35.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
xarray                    0.16.1                     py_0  
xz                        5.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0  
zict                      2.0.0                      py_0  
zipp                      3.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3  
zstd                      1.3.3                h84994c4_0
```

Comment: [update] When I created new conda environment, `conda install pip` and   `pip install pyqt5 pyqtwebengine`  everthing works fine. Is there a way to repair my current environment to work with pyqtwebengine, because I need packages which are already installed.

Comment: The problem is that there is conflict with the conda qt with the one used by the pyqtwebengine installed by pip. The solution is to install the packages only using conda

Comment: I am having a similar problem with pyside2 and I can't solve it. Also the linked solution doesn't work for me. On top of that it seems like a new environment uses python3.9 instead of 3.8. And pyside2 works there as @grzegorzs described. I guess it is a 3.8 problem.

Comment: I managed to run it on a new conda environment with python3.9 [conda env](https://gofile.io/d/cJ7v1S)